# Simple python web-crawler

Tags: python, url, web-crawler

I have been searching for a simple, working, and web-crawler (also know as a spider) and have not been able to find one. Could anyone help me with this problem? I would like it to simply get all the links from a specified url as well as all the links from each of the urls it scanned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tried making a webcrawler before. However, I imagine it shouldn't be too complicated. I will give you a couple resources you can use.

I do not know any module that will simply fetch all the links for you, so you will have to probably go through the process yourself.

First, get the HTML from you link with [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html). Then, parse the HTML and find the links with [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). There is even a section on the page that describes how to get all the links from a webpage.

This is really all the "difficult" code. You can then append all the links you got to a list, go through each link, repeat the same process as above, and then add the resulting links to the list again, and recursively repeat this process for however long you want. That should make a basic web crawler for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) module.

Alternatively, you can write your own crawlers, using a combination of a module for fetching data (i.e. requests, urllib2, or selenium) and some HTML parser (BeautifulSoup or selenium's built-in parser).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as a web crawler but I am not sure if it will work or not because it gives me some errors but you might have another python path installed

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


    def trade_spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
    url = "https://buckysroom.org/trade/search.php?page=" + str(page)
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    # just get the code, no headers or anything
    plain_text = source_code.text
    # BeautifulSoup objects can be sorted through easy
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
    for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'item-name'}):
        href = "https://buckysroom.org" + link.get('href')
        title = link.string  # just the text, not the HTML
        print(href)
        print(title)
        # get_single_item_data(href)
    page += 1


def get_single_item_data(item_url):
source_code = requests.get(item_url)
plain_text = source_code.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
# if you want to gather information from that page
for item_name in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'i-name'}):
    print(item_name.string)
 # if you want to gather links for a web crawler
 for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    href = "https://buckysroom.org" + link.get('href')
    print(href)


trade_spider(1)
```